# Marshal generic return types for com interop

Tags: .net, generics, com, interop

Is it possible to Marshal a generic return type as non-generic for COM interop?

Let's say I have the following class:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetStr() // Generic return type
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

I know that IEnumerable<string> implements IEnumerable.

Can I force tlbexp.exe (via return: attribute or via some other way) to expose GetStr() method
as a method returning IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, no. When you hit limitations with COM interop marshaling, it's usually better to create a separate wrapper type with a COM friendly interface, and leave the original type as .NET friendly as possible.

Comment: OK, but how do you do that?!?

Comment: @CoderDennis: Add a wrapper method with a non-generic return value, e.g., `public IEnumerable GetStrInterop() { return GetStr(); }`, and use this method for interop.